# xml confusion in sql

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2005

hey,
am making a program that makes the forms and controls dynamically from xml format in C#.
i found in MS SQL data type XML but dnt know how to manupolate it? how to store xml in it nd how get it back??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look on : http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/16032

Answer (score 0):

If you use LINQ2SQL as database connection method, your xml-field should be of the type `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`, the newer xml format for .NET.

Mind you, the absolutely maximum size for this field is approximately 64k characters. That may sound like much, but believe me, it's not.